# Why is " I" not " me" required in this comparative clause?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

1. He is taller than ***I***.
2. He is taller than ***me***.

I saw both sentences on an official website of a famous university in Indiana, USA. On the grammar page,
sentence one is an example of how personal pronouns are used. While sentence two is considered negative and ungrammatical. In the Oxford Dictionary, sentence two is correct because " than" is defined as a preposition. So, I'm wondering, which should I trust.

Comment: Your research doesn't indicate it's *required* but only provides evidence it's *not required*, so why are you asking a question that contradicts the findings of your own research? Also, don't confuse *style* with *grammar*. If some conspicuously and suspiciously unnamed "famous university" in Indiana *may* allegedly require its writers use "I" instead of "me" (only "may" since you fail to actually say it does), that's an issue of style, not grammar. Oxford University saying "me" is acceptable is *grammar*, but if it told its writers not to use "I," which is also grammatical, that'd be *style*.

Comment: @ Benjamin Harman, Sorry, if my examples (or I ) may mislead you about the point. It is truly said on the webpage of Purdue University at OWL.purdue.edu, that " me " is incorrect and ungrammatical in the second example.

Comment: @Laurel, Thanks for your link. I've got it.

Comment: They are both possible, though nominative "I" is considered overly formal.